# Show spinner in Ionic framework at the time of $http post request

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-http

Thank you for look on this question. 
How to show spinner while $http post request is completed in Ionic framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all the details from ionic spinner [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/)

in your html template file, use ionic spinner like this.

```
<ion-spinner icon="spiral" ng-if="isLoading"></ion-spinner>
```

and in your controller file, you can make spinner work like this,

```
$scope.isLoading = true;
$http.post(url, body,config).succcess(function(res) {
      $scope.isLoading = false;
})
.error(function(err) {
      $scope.isLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Ameer Hamza , but I have one doubt too. How can I set time    limit on http connection with spinner.

Comment: Time limit in the sense, time limit for http call or time limit for spinner ?